# PostgreSQL - Using logical replication for high availability with one replica

Tags: postgresql, replication

Scenario :

1. Logical replication is configured from system 1 to system 2 (System 1 is the primary)
2. When system 1 fails, we switch to the system 2 for transaction (system 2 becomes the primary)
3. When system 1 is up again, we want logical replication from system 2 to system 1 (system 2 continues as the primary till it fails)
4. When system 2 fails, we switch to the system 1 for transaction (system 1 becomes the primary)
5. Only 1 PostgreSQL node is used for transaction at a time, other system PostgreSQL node will not have any transaction at that time
6. Physical replication is not an option as we need triggers to fire on the secondary system which is on standby. Physical replication makes it read-only
7. Any data loss is not an option
8. Postgres extensions can be used (but no licensed third party tools)

Not much knowledge on PostgreSQL replication, but from what I understood some issues are there with the logical replication slots and its not safe during failover/fallback.

With the latest version of PostgreSQL, what possible drawbacks are there if we want to use logical replication for high availability? (failover/fallback with one primary and one secondary system)

Comment: If ANY data loss is not an option then you need synchronous physical replication afaik. Otherwise even with servers in the same rack there is the network lag to consider.

Comment: Logical replication is not suitable for a high availability solution.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid data loss, the best way is to use streaming synchronous replication.

If you can't use it and prefer to use logical replication instead, the safest way to avoid data loss in this case is to rebuild the subscriber node after every failover process.

Keep in mind that you'll need to create the schema first or restore a backup in the subscriber node, as database schema and DDL commands are [not replicated in logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/logical-replication-restrictions.html).